# How to fire event off YesNo Alert Box?

Tags: apache-flex, alert, flex4.5

This is very basic and there are [samples](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=controls_19.html) out there, but I am still struggling.

I need to fire an alert with a yes/no option.
I need to do this in actionscript.

```
Alert.show("Open new tab to search in Google Maps?",
"No places found", Alert.YES | Alert.NO, this, alertListener, null, Alert.NO);

function alertListener(eventObj:CloseEvent):void {

   if (eventObj.detail==Alert.YES) {
    Alert.show("You clicked yes"); 
    }
}
```

This returns an exception with the flash debug player:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert mx.rpc::AsyncResponder@e31c601 to flash.display.Sprite.
    at Function/ExampleCustomTools.Locator:locator/private:doFind/ExampleCustomTools.Locator:onResult()[C:\Users\sjackson\Adobe Flash Builder 4\DekhoSimulator_Profiler\src\ExampleCustomTools\Locator\locator.mxml:142]
    at mx.rpc::AsyncResponder/result()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncResponder.as:95]
    at com.esri.ags.tasks::Locator/handleAddressCandidates()[C:\checkout\flex_api2\api\src\com\esri\ags\tasks\Locator.as:187]
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::call()
    at com.esri.ags.tasks::BaseTask/handleResult()[C:\checkout\flex_api2\api\src\com\esri\ags\tasks\BaseTask.as:667]
    at Function/com.esri.ags.tasks:BaseTask/esri_internal:sendURLVariables2/com.esri.ags.tasks:result()[C:\checkout\flex_api2\api\src\com\esri\ags\tasks\BaseTask.as:604]
    at mx.rpc::Responder/result()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\Responder.as:56]
    at mx.rpc::AsyncToken/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::applyResult()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncToken.as:239]
    at mx.rpc.events::ResultEvent/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::callTokenResponders()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\events\ResultEvent.as:207]
    at HTTPOperation/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::dispatchRpcEvent()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\http\HTTPService.as:991]
    at mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::resultHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AbstractInvoker.as:318]
    at mx.rpc::Responder/result()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\Responder.as:56]
    at mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/acknowledge()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncRequest.as:84]
    at DirectHTTPMessageResponder/completeHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\channels\DirectHTTPChannel.as:451]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

I have tried several variations of the code, but still get errors.
Apologies for such a trivial Q, but appreciate any help on pointing out whats wrong and the most elegant way of doing this.

[Here is the code in its fuller context at pastebin (line 31).](http://pastebin.com/Y2WieEUP)

Comment: Done. I am new to programming - if I step through, it falls over on the alert line so I assumed this was the cause?  I will do some reading on why its struggling to convert the AsyncResponder.

Comment: Show please the code of locator.mxml

Comment: The Error is not in Alert. That error is related to type conversion. Please check the "result event" in BaseTask.as file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I should have persevered on my own a bit more.
Code fix below:

```
Alert.show("Open new tab to search in Google Maps?", "No places found", Alert.YES | Alert.NO, null, alertListener, null, Alert.NO);

                         function alertListener(eventObj:CloseEvent):void {
                             // Check to see if the OK button was pressed.
                             if (eventObj.detail==Alert.YES) {
                                 Alert.show("here"); 
                             }
                         }
```